# Set local IP address for IKEv2 VPN connection using macOS built-in VPN client

Tags: network, vpn

I'm trying to connect to an IKEv2 VPN server using the macOS 13.5.2 Ventura built-in VPN client. I used Apple Configurator 2 to access all possible settings for the connection.

Unfortunately, I cannot connect to the VPN because the macOS client requests the virtual IP `%any`, and the server replies with an `INTERNAL_ADDRESS_FAILURE`. Instead, for my scenario, I need the client to ask for a specific virtual IP.

I would like to know if it's possible to do so using the macOS built-in VPN client.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to set the IP from the IKEv2 client.  Surely it is normal for the server to decide what IP address the client should use. Have you talked to the administrator of the server?

Comment: @Gilby Unfortunately I need to have a specific client IP address for my use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using [strongSwan](https://www.strongswan.org).
It can be installed on macOS using Homebrew (more info [here](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/os/macos.html)).
It offers a lot of options, including setting the local IP using the `local_ts` traffic selector in `swanctl.conf`.

However, it doesn't offer a GUI anymore and therefore it might be a bit more complicated to use compared to other proposed solutions (e.g. [IPSecuritas](https://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/)).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "virtual IP" means that your clients needs to use a specific client IP address:

Searching [Apple's Configuration Profile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf), I did not find an option to set the client IP for an IPSec VPN.

You may want to try using the free [IPSecuritas](https://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/) VPN client instead, which has a few advantages over the macOS built-in IPSec VPN client, one of them being that is allows you to set a client IP address.

Disclaimer: I'm just a user of said software, and I don’t have any connections to its author.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited the question title to make the issue more clear. I'll give IPSecuritas a try, although I managed to solve the issue using strongSwan.

Comment: I tried IPSecuritas, however it doesn't seem to support IKEv2, can you confirm?

Comment: @Matteo I’m pretty sure it does, but I can’t verify, as I currently don’t have access to my Mac.